# Dipole array antenna radiation pattern

Tags: antenna, antenna-array, dipole

I have the radiation pattern for a dipole antenna with working frequency of 11 GHz, it looks like figure 1. I wanted to create an array antenna consisting of 2 elements with that same individual radiation pattern and a spacing of 0.75*wavelength, it should look something like figure 2.

My doubt is, how do I create the antenna pattern for the array, with the single element radiation pattern? In other words, how do I create figure 2 using figure 1?

[image: Single dipole antenna pattern]
Figure 1

[image: 2 element dipole antenna array with spacing of 0.75*wavelenth]
Figure 2

Comment: What makes you think that there's a simple transformation that you can apply to Figure 1 to get Figure 2? The software that created these figures went to a lot of work to integrate the field contributions of the two conductors.

Comment: @DaveTweed Why do you assume that I think there is a simple transformation? The figure 1 to figure 2 think was just a way of talking.

Comment: In your own words, *"...how do I create figure 2 using figure 1?"* How else was I supposed to interpret that?

Comment: @DaveTweed You totally missed my first question: “how do I create the antenna patter for the array with the single element radiation pattern?”. Anyways, you’ve been very helpful

Comment: If I understand the question correctly, you're trying to create a standard linear antenna array consisting of two elements. The total radiation pattern of such an array is approximated by the product of the element factor (your first figure, the pattern of a single element), and the array factor (the pattern resulting from the constructive/destructive summation of the two patterns, assuming omnidirectional antennas). There's complete derivations in many antenna books, for example Stutzman and Thiele's Antenna Theory and Design.

Comment: @DaDSPGuy Your first picture looks a lot like one momentary snapshot of a very short (with respect to wavelenth) dipole wire (along the z-axis), center-driven. The study of spherical harmonics using Laplace (in spherical coordinates) is the right study domain, I think. But as you didn't specify "short" in the first case, nor center-driven either. So I remain a bit confused about the question generally. I think LetterSized has perhaps provided some references. But due to my own confusion about your "array consisting of 2 elements," I can't add anything constructive, right now.

Comment: In short, the array factor is computed by summing the fields from each antenna with the appropriate phase shift. Assuming each antenna is driven by the same signal in phase, then the phase seen at some point (x,y,z), assuming omnidirectionality, is related to the distance to each antenna. Since the antennas are separated by some appreciable distance, you'll get different phase shifts from the two antennas. And so at some points, they will be in phase (your main and side loves) and at some points they will be out of phase (your nulls).

Answer (score 1):

Part of the answer is in the comments of the question. In order to compute the directivity of an array antenna first you need to compute the electrical field produced by one of the antenna elements. Once you have computed it, you will need to compute the **array factor**, which is given by

$$AF(\theta, \phi) = \sum_{m = 0}^{N - 1} I_m e^{j(k \hat{r} \cdot \mathbf{r_m})}$$

with $$\mathbf{r_m}$$ being the position vector the element *m* of the antenna, $$I_m$$ the complex amplitude of the excitation of the element *m*, and
$$\hat{r} = \sin{\theta} \; cos{\phi} \; \hat{x} + \sin{\theta} \; \sin{\phi} \hat{y} + \cos{\theta} \; \hat{z}$$

The **total array pattern** is given by the multiplication of the array factor and the element radiation pattern, the previously computed electrical field of the antenna element. Finally, the directivity is given by

$$D = \frac{U(\theta, \phi)}{\frac{1}{4\pi} \int_0^{2\pi} \int_0^{\pi} \frac{U(\theta, \phi)}{\max{\{U(\theta, \phi)\}}} \sin{\theta} d\theta d\phi}$$

where $$U(\theta, \phi)$$ is the radiation pattern. The radiation pattern is given by

$$U(\theta, \phi) = |B(\theta, \phi)|^2$$

with $$B(\theta, \phi)$$ being the normalized total array pattern.

Please note that the spherical coordinates are given by figure 1.

[image: Figure 1: Spherical coordinates]

Figure 1